# Can you clone contents of an element into canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I was wondering if it's possible to clone an HTML element into canvas.  So looking at this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0yf56rvy/), how would you duplicate it into canvas?

I've seen ways to [draw DOM objects into a canvas element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Drawing_DOM_objects_into_a_canvas), but I was curious if there was a way to do it differently.

```
<p>Html</p>
<div id="clone-me">
  <div id="square">
  </div>
</div>

<p>Canvas</p>
<canvas width="200" height="200"></canvas>

#clone-me {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #333;
}

#square {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  background: red;
}
```

Comment: No you can't and this page should be removed from MDN. That's a hack and only partially works with some elements in some browsers.
html2canvas library is indeed the closest solution to this problem, but it's still in beta and some CSS won't render. An other solution is for chrome, to use the [desktopCapture API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/desktopCapture), fortunately only accessible to extensions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [the most upvoted \[canvas\] question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/canvas?sort=votes), aka [Using HTML5/Canvas/JavaScript to take screenshots](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912092/using-html5-canvas-javascript-to-take-screenshots)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [html2canvas](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas) to do it, you can checkout the demo at this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0yf56rvy/2/).

```
html2canvas(document.getElementById('clone-me'), {
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
        var canvas1 = document.getElementById('canvas1');
        var ctx = canvas1.getContext('2d');
        ctx.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0);
    }
});
```